# Solve struggling with two equations in two unknowns

Tags: equation-solving

I have a two equations and two unknowns. I tried to solve the equations with *Mathematica*, but it is having trouble. It has been saying

> Running...

for quite a long time. Here is my system:

```
sol = 
  Solve[{
    (1 + β/(1 - α)) ρ/(((1 - σ) β)/(1 - α) + 1/(1 - σ) -  1/(ϕ c)) == 
      (α k^(α - 1) - ρ)/σ, 
    (β/(1 - α)) ρ/(((1 - σ) β)/(1 - α) + 1/(1 - σ) - 1/(ϕ c)) == 
       k^(α - 1) - c}, {c, k}]
```

What could be the reason for *Mathematica* taking so long? Does it mean it is impossible for it to find `c` and `k`?

Comment: Try making the substitution `k^(α - 1) -> t` before solving.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about that. It has actually worked with giving a one positive and one negative value. This is due to terms with powers I think.